# Sql query to return data if AVG(7 days record count) > (Today's record count)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a SQL query in **Oracle database** for:

A priceindex(field name) have around 120(say) records each day and I have to display the priceindex name and today's date, if  the avg of last 7 days record count is greater than Todays record count for the priceindex(group by priceindex).

Basically, There will be 56 priceindex and each should have around 120 records each day and is dump to database each day from external site. So want to make sure all records are downloaded to the database everyday.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: The problem seems to ask you/us to predict the future. Presumably today's FULL count (until midnight) must be considered. It is only 11 a.m. now, when I run the query; how on Earth do I know what "today's count" will be? The day is not over yet!  Please clarify.

Comment: It is running Every morning at 12.00 AM

Comment: So then, do you mean YESTERDAY's count, and not TODAY's count? If you run something at midnight, it is for the day that just ENDED, and that's called YESTERDAY, no? And, then - when you say "seven days prior", does that INCLUDE the day for which you run the report, or is it seven days NOT including the date of interest?

Comment: Not include the date of interest

Answer (score 3):

Except for the clarification I requested in a Comment to your question (having to do with "how can we know today's final count, when today is not over yet), the problem can be solved along the following lines. Not tested since you didn't provide sample data.

From your table, select only the rows where the relevant DATE is between "today" - 7 and "today" (so there are really EIGHT days: the seven days preceding today, and today). Then group by PRICEINDEX. Count total rows for each group, and count rows just for "today". The rows for "today" should be less than 1/8 times the total count (this is easy algebra: this is equivalent to being less than 1/7 times the count of OTHER days).

Such conditions, at the group level, must be in the HAVING clause.

```
select   priceindex
from     your_table
where    datefield >= trunc(sysdate) - 7 and datefield < trunc(sysdate) + 1
group by priceindex
having   count(case when datefield >= trunc(sysdate) then 1 end) < 1/8 * count(*)
;
```

**EDIT** The OP clarified that the query runs every day at midnight; this means that "today" should actually mean "yesterday" (the day that just ended). In Oracle, and probably in all of computing, midnight belongs to the day that BEGINS at midnight, not the one that ends at midnight. The time-of-day at midnight is 00:00:00 (beginning of the new day), not 24:00:00.

So, the query above will have to be changed slightly:

```
select   priceindex
from     your_table
where    datefield >= trunc(sysdate) - 8 and datefield < trunc(sysdate)
group by priceindex
having   count(case when datefield >= trunc(sysdate) - 1 then 1 end)
         < 1/8 * count(*)
;
```